# Capture video of applications from an Android device

Tags: android, video-capture

I need to make some videos of Android applications for a presentation. All solutions I found in the Android SDK can only take pictures. Is there a possibility to create a video - for example on a rooted device?

edit: I found the project droidAtScreen but the frame rate isn't very good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed a few times on the `android-developers` Google Group, such as [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/dca0f22b3c480b1a/a6f5650f4c7f4a3f) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/d8bcbe7e44ca466c/ba70d85739381d4e).

Comment: which both does not have a real answer on how to do it, just pathetic workarounds for the problems...

Answer (score 1):

I work for lunarg.com and we have a solution via a free SDK (in Beta1 stage right now) that allows developer to create  "record" button that calls our library and we will capture all of the OpenGl calls - thus there is no overhead that could impact the performance of the device, for example during a gameplay.
After the capture is done, the file is uploaded in the background via `WiFi` to our server where it is converted to a video and posted to the user specified `YouTube` or video.

If you want you can look at the results here http://www.lunarg.com/seemegaming/